# Java Applet button

Tags: java, swing, applet

i have created a button where it should run a piece of code that analyses text which the user has input into a text field. The code works fine but i cant get the code to work when pressed just by the 'Analyze' button, instead it still does it when pressed by the reset button too, i have tried adding the ActionListener but it still doesnt seem to work?

```
/* Creating Analyze and Reset buttons */

       JButton countButton = new JButton("Analyze");
       //countButton.addActionListener(this);
       south.add(countButton);

       JButton resetButton = new JButton("Reset");
       resetButton.addActionListener(this);
       south.add(resetButton);

/ Text analysis start
    countButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {
    String[] array = textInput.getText().split(" ");
    int maxWordLength = 0;
    int wordLength = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      array[i] = array[i].replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", ""); 
        wordLength = array[i].length();
        if (wordLength > maxWordLength) {
            maxWordLength = wordLength;
        }
    }
    int[] intArray = new int[maxWordLength + 1];
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    intArray[array[i].length()]++;
}
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(sw);
out.print("<html>");
for (int i = 1; i < intArray.length; i++) {
    out.printf("%d word(s) of length %d<br>", intArray[i], i);
}
out.print("</html>");
wordCountLabel.setText(sw.toString());
```

}
        }};

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: What is the actionPerformed method on ```this```?

Comment: @NeplatnyUdaj i want the method to be the piece of code starting " String[] array", i want that code to be executed when the analyze button is clicked?

Comment: I understand that. But this piece of code ```resetButton.addActionListener(this);``` means that the object where you are creating the buttons also implements ActionListener so there must be another ```actionPerformed``` which you're not showing. The action listener in your code is an anonymous class used only for the countButton.

Comment: iv resolved the issue. thanks

Comment: I'm confused. What was in the other actionPerformed? Or is the piece of code in non-working state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling the same `ActionListener` for both button presses, so you need to differentiate what to do in the `actionPerformed()` method.  Use `getActionCommand()` for this:

```
public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {
   String command = e.getActionCommand();

   if (command.equals("Analyze")) {
      // doAnalyze();
   } else if (command.equals("Reset")) {
      // doReset();
   }
}
```